# Upload Excel data to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, insert, node.js

I am trying to read excel data and insert it into a SQL Server database. I am using npm package mssql to do the same. Also using XLSX to read Excel data.

However I keep getting the same error

```
ErrorMessageToken { name: 'ERROR', event: 'errorMessage', number: 102, state: 1, class: 15, message: 'Incorrect syntax near '?'.', serverName: 'myservername', procName: '', lineNumber: 1 } }, name: 'RequestError', number: 102, lineNumber: 1, state: 1, class: 15, serverName: 'myservername', procName: '', precedingErrors: [] }
```

My code:

```js
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'demo.XLSX')
const workbook = XLSX.readFile(filePath)
const [firstSheetName] = workbook.SheetNames
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName]

const rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
    raw: true, // Use raw values (true) or formatted strings (false)
    header: 1, // Generate an array of arrays ("2D Array")
})

const pool = await connect({
    user: process.env.dbUser,
    password: process.env.dbPassword,
    server: process.env.dbServer,
    database: process.env.dbName,
    options: {
            encrypt: true,
            enableArithAbort: true,
    },
})

const query = `INSERT INTO TableName (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5) VALUES ?  `
const result = await pool.request().query(query, [rows])
// also tried ...rows, [[rows]], [rows.values()]
console.log(result)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I think this is more suited for Stack Overflow, it's a node.js question on how to use .request().query(). Somehow your syntax doesn't fill in the rows in the query correctly which results in an invalid query.

Comment: DOes the syntax with `?` work at all? Try `console.log(rows)` before the query to see the actual structure of `rows`. I would agree that this is a general JavaScript question and not specific for database.

Comment: `rows` is a JSON blob, yes? How should that be applied across `(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)`?

Comment: console.log(rows) is a 2d array, if I set header: 0, I get a json with keys as table column names and values as actual row values

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tired ?, ? ... but it doesnot work